# Case When statement to identify integer/non-integer

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing an SQL for an Oracle Database that has a Case When statement for a calculation. The current method like '1' does not give me all integers, so I'm looking for a way to be able to say if NBR_UNITS/STD_PACK_QTY is an integer then 'Case pick' and if it's a decimal then 'Unit Pick'.

Below is the section of the SQL has it stands now:

```
CASE
WHEN (NBR_UNITS/STD_PACK_QTY) like '1' THEN 'Case Pick'
WHEN (NBR_UNITS/STD_PACK_QTY) < '1' THEN 'Unit Pick'
ELSE 'Error'
END "Case Picks"
```

Below is an example of the data. I'm trying to get the SQL to output 'Case Pick' if the division calculation is any integer and then 'Unit Pick' if it is any decimal.

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTngb.png)

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: So what do you want the result to be if the fraction equals 1.3? It will be "error" in your current thinking.

Comment: If it's any fraction, the output should be 'Unit Pick', if it's any integer it should be 'Case Pick'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for this specific example is using the `MOD` function.

```
CASE
WHEN MOD(NBR_UNITS,STD_PACK_QTY) > 0 THEN 'Case Pick'
WHEN MOD(NBR_UNITS,STD_PACK_QTY) = 0 THEN 'Unit Pick'
END "Case Picks"
```

Comment: Or the othe way around. Other than that, yes, this is the most efficient answer.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to check if any numeric expression `x` is an integer or not is

```
case when x = round(x) then ...
     when x < 1        then...
     else                  ...   end   as ....
```

(assuming comparing to 1 is the right thing; not sure about that, I asked a clarification question in a Comment below the original post).

Answer (score 0):

Compare the division to the trunc/floor/round down of the division.

```
WHEN (NBR_UNITS/STD_PACK_QTY) = TRUNC(NBR_UNITS/STD_PACK_QTY) THEN 'Case Pick'
```

Not sure what your rules are as to whether you can just use ELSE to capture everything else - i.e., if case qty is 24 and they give you 36, is that okay?  If so then ELSE captures basically everything else, right?  While if that's not okay and unit qty is only okay for < 24, then `ELSE (NBR_UNITS/STD_PACK_QTY) < 1` works and ELSE can be an error.

Answer (score 0):

Since integers extend beyond 9, you might consider the TRUNC() function.  It removes the fractional part of the result.  Therefore when TRUNC(Result) equals Result the Result is integer.

```
    WITH
     "Data" AS
        (
            SELECT 1 AS NBR_UNITS, 8 AS STD_PACK_QTY FROM dual
            UNION
            SELECT 2 AS NBR_UNITS, 8 AS STD_PACK_QTY FROM dual
            UNION
            SELECT 3 AS NBR_UNITS, 8 AS STD_PACK_QTY FROM dual
            UNION
            SELECT 4 AS NBR_UNITS, 8 AS STD_PACK_QTY FROM dual
            UNION
            SELECT 5 AS NBR_UNITS, 8 AS STD_PACK_QTY FROM dual
            UNION
            SELECT 6 AS NBR_UNITS, 8 AS STD_PACK_QTY FROM dual
            UNION
            SELECT 7 AS NBR_UNITS, 8 AS STD_PACK_QTY FROM dual
            UNION
            SELECT 8 AS NBR_UNITS, 8 AS STD_PACK_QTY FROM dual
            UNION
            SELECT 9 AS NBR_UNITS, 8 AS STD_PACK_QTY FROM dual
        )
SELECT
     NBR_UNITS
    ,STD_PACK_QTY
    ,NBR_UNITS/STD_PACK_QTY     AS "Ratio"
    ,CASE
        WHEN (TRUNC(NBR_UNITS/STD_PACK_QTY) = NBR_UNITS/STD_PACK_QTY)   THEN    'Case Pick'
        WHEN (TRUNC(NBR_UNITS/STD_PACK_QTY) < 1)                    THEN    'Unit Pick'
        ELSE                                                'Error'
     END                        AS "Case Picks"
FROM "Data"
;
```